# Run appium from eclipse with testng throws Could not start a new session error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

On Appium, I have set the server to be 127.0.0.1 and port 4725; I have also loaded an .app file same as in the /path/to.app below.

In java, I have:

```
@BeforeMethod //testng framework
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // set up appium
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.1");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
    capabilities.setCapability("app","/path/to.app");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```

So first of all, I have appium opened but not in launched mode; I then try to run the project but then given the following error:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

full console output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /private/var/folders/hh/r5f5h1lx23g6drvycy03g29w0000gs/T/testng-eclipse-1079178856/testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'my-host', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
at com.tribehr.ios.ios_test.NewTest.setUp(NewTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
... 30 more

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
SKIPPED: test01

===============================================

    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

==============================================


===============================================

Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@7b1d7fff: 27 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@5f205aa: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2437c6dc: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@67f89fa3: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2ff5659e: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 3 ms
```

I am just wondering what do I miss?

Comment: Please post the Appium logs

Comment: @sheeptest I have edited the post; is that what you are asking for? because I don't know if appium is writing logs itself.

Comment: When you run the appium server from the command line, it should print out logs.

Comment: @sheeptest I am using Appium UI to run it; if I do it from command line it says appium will not work if used or installed with sudo... Also, when I run it on UI I won't launch the app, and thus won't produce any logs..

Comment: so I got the logs, which is fairly simple: 
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4725
info: LogLevel: debug
and no more is produced..

Comment: So your code isn't even getting to Appium. Can you try taking the `BeforeMethod` out and seeing if just the most basic implementation works?

Comment: @sheeptest I don't even know what I did and then it worked... but throws null pointerexception at another line... I have post another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769181/appiumdriver-gives-null-pointer-exception Please provide feedbacks if you have any clue, thanks!