# Cannot instantiate the type AppiumDriver

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have added following jars in my projects build path:

1. java-client-2.0.0 from http://appium.io/downloads.html >> Appium Client libraries >> Java
2. selenium-java-2.43.1
3. selenium-java-2.43.1-srcs
4. selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1
   and here's my code:

   ```
   public class SampleApp{

   WebDriver dr;

   @Test
   public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
       String apkpath = "D:\\apkdump\\sampleapp.apk";
       File app = new File (apkpath);
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","TestADB18");
       capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
       capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
       capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.test");
       capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sampleapp.Main");
       dr = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
       dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   }


   }
   ```

   I am getting red line below `new AppiumDriver` which says that `Cannot instantiate the type AppiumDriver`. Now if remove all `selenium jars` the error disappears but then I can't resolve errors with webdriver.

   **What is the conflict between jars?**

   I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769181/appiumdriver-gives-null-pointer-exception) but that could run the code and was getting `Null pointer exception` but in my case I cant even run it, it is giving run on saving the code. Secondly the **answer has been posted without using** `AppiumDriver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be fixed by downgrading the `Appium Client`(see step 1 in my question) from latest to `java-client-1.5.0`. You can keep rest of the jars to latest.

Downgraded version of `Appium Client` can be downloaded from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/1.5.0

Comment: It works for 1.6.2 as well on mine. But why not having new version, which will be supported and extended?

Answer (score 25):

You don't need to downgrade or anything. There is a design change in the Java Client version 2.0.0 as they mention on their [site](https://github.com/appium/java-client#changelog):

> AppiumDriver is now an abstract class, use IOSDriver and AndroidDriver which both extend it.

So, just change your driver line to be:

```
dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),getDesiredCapabilities("192.21.168.56:5555"));
```

use this. and import:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
```

Answer (score 0):

dr=new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

proper URL to be established

Answer (score 0):

for appium version 1.7 use capability 
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");

while for v1.8.1
its not needed