# Unable to run appium test due to appiumDriver

Tags: java, android, appium, serenity-bdd

Been having this issue in my stack trace when trying to run my appium and I have been trying a lot of things to fix it but no luck. What do I need to do to fix the following issue?

```
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_201
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 130 ms - 598
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"./xxxx.apk","appPackage":"xxxx","hub":"http://xxxx:xxxx/wd/hub","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"appium","appWaitActivity":"xxx.xxxx.LoginActivity","browserName":"","udid":"xxx","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Galaxy S6"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
[Appium] DeprecationWarning: 'automationName' capability was not provided. Future versions of Appium will require 'automationName' capability to be set for Android sessions.
```

Further down it then states:

```
Tests in error: 
  Could not instantiate class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
  Could not instantiate class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
```

Calling from serenity properties:

```
webdriver.driver= appium
appium.hub = http://xxx/wd/hub
appium.automationName=appium
appium.platformName = Android

####### Android CAPS Real Device ######

appium.platformVersion = 6.0.1
appium.browserName =
serenity.take.screenshots= AFTER_EACH_STEP
webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait = 5000


appium.app=./xxx.apk
appium.appPackage = xxx
appium.appWaitActivity = xxx.LoginActivity

## TestTeam Galaxy S6
appium.deviceName = Galaxy S6
appium.udid = xxx
```

Comment: You said that you tried a lot of things, what have you tried?

Comment: @Pristin - Could you please post the Java code how you are invoking the Appium driver ?

Comment: @Manidroid I am doing it through serenity, I will post above

Comment: @CosminO I tired including java client in pom file for io.appium, tried installing and updating the android driver, tried relocating my android driver in environment variables, tried updating my appium version

Comment: @Pristin - Could you please post full appium logs

Comment: @Pristin Were you able to find a solution for this. If yes can you please post it here?

Answer (score 2):

> Appium Driver is an abstract class starting from Java Client version
>   2.0.0.

You have to instantiate either AndroidDriver or IOSDriver specifically( and not AppiumDriver).
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26901919/5551621) answer.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing this sentence in the capabilities , you can use this or

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
```

this

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator");
```

I have shared the link with you so you should understand why do we use the capability in appium

http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/

http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator/

let us know that works or not..

Comment: I'm calling through serenity, see above